# Cómo mostrar un elemento de un JSON de acuerdo a un ID String con REACT

Tags: array, json, reactjs

estoy tratando de hacer un llamado a un id que no es numérico, es un string, y parece no funcionar, no estoy segura de si tenga algo que ver con que no es numérico. Porque no funciona colocando ''. Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Así tengo mis productos en JSON:

```
{
        "id": "jean06",
        "title": "Jeans",
        "imagen": "img/JEAN-PORTADA.webp",
        "categoria": {
            "name": "jeans",
            "id": "jeans"
        },
        "precio": 250,
        "stock": 30
    },
```

Pero cuando intento recorrerlo no me funciona, esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

```
const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
    const [producto, setProducto] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('./json/jeans.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(products => {
                const item = products.find(prod => prod.id === 'jeans')
            })
    }, [])
```

Comment: El recorrido no te va a funcionar porque tu json no es un array, para indicar que es un array, todos tus datos u objetos los tienes que meter con []

Comment: Coloca un `console.log(Array.isArray(products))` dentro del último `then` e indicanos que resultado obtienes

Comment: Creo que el JSON que compartió es una muestra del array entero, pero no queda claro de todas formas. Debería agregar todo el JSON (Con algunos items nomás). Otro error que noto es que `prod.id === 'jeans'` no va a coincidir con el `id` del ejemplo que agregó: `"id": "jean06"`. Siendo que `jean06` no es igual a `jeans`